# Is it possible to partition a view, like table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, view, database-partitioning

I have created view from UNION ALL clause of around 10 tables and want to apply some search queries by date range on it. But as number of records increases it takes longer to execute the query. Right now the view is having 2 billion rows.

Table structure is like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_queue_stats_0716` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `server_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
    `uniqueid` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `queue_datetime` datetime NOT NULL, 
    `queue_timestamp` varchar(100) NULL, 
    `qname_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
    `qagent_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
    `qevent_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
    `info1` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `info2` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `info3` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `info4` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `info5` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Tables are created on monthly basis , so there can be tables like tbl_queue_stats_0616, tbl_queue_stats_0516, tbl_queue_stats_0416...

And I want to apply search query on multiple tables if date range required to search from 2 or more months.

Search query is look like:

```
select  server_id,server_name,queue_id,queue_name,qevent_id,event,
        count(id) as cnt,sum(info1) as info1, sum(info2) as info2,
        sum(info3) as info3, sum(info4) as info4, sum(info5) as info5,
        max(cast(info2 AS SIGNED)) as max_info2,
        max(cast(info3 AS SIGNED)) as max_info3
   from
      ( SELECT  a.server_id as server_id,e.server_name as server_name,
                a.id,a.`queue_datetime`, b.agent, a.qname_id as queue_id ,
               c.queue as queue_name,d.event,a.qevent_id,a.info1,a.info2,
               a.info3,a.info4,a.info5
            FROM  view_queue_stats a,tbl_qagent b, tbl_qname c, tbl_qevent d,
                tbl_server e
            WHERE  a.qagent_id=b.id
              AND  a.qname_id=c.id
              AND  a.qevent_id=d.id
              AND  a.server_id=e.id
              AND  DATE(a.queue_datetime) between '" . $start_date .
                                           "' AND '" . $end_date . "'
              AND  a.server_id IN ($server_name) 
      )as total
    GROUP BY  qevent_id,queue_id,server_id
    ORDER BY  length(server_name), server_name,queue_id,qevent_id.
```

I think search through partitioned view can execute my query faster. To achieve this I applied partition related parameters to create view but not succeeded.

Below is Output of SHOW CREATE VIEW view_queue_stats;

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER 
       VIEW `view_queue_stats`
       AS    select  `tbl_queue_stats_0116`.`id` AS `id`,
       `tbl_queue_stats_0116`.`server_id` AS `server_id`,
       `tbl_queue_stats_0116`.`uniqueid` AS `uniqueid`,
       `tbl_queue_stats_0116`.`queue_datetime` AS `queue_datetime`,
       `tbl_queue_stats_0116`.`queue_timestamp` AS `queue_timestamp`,
       `tbl_queue_stats_0116`.`qname_id` AS `qname_id`,
       `tbl_queue_stats_0116`.`qagent_id` AS `qagent_id`,
       `tbl_queue_stats_0116`.`qevent_id` AS `qevent_id`,
       `tbl_queue_stats_0116`.`info1` AS `info1`,
       `tbl_queue_stats_0116`.`info2` AS `info2`,
       `tbl_queue_stats_0116`.`info3` AS `info3`,
       `tbl_queue_stats_0116`.`info4` AS `info4`,
       `tbl_queue_stats_0116`.`info5` AS `info5`
    from  `tbl_queue_stats_0116`
    union  all 
select  `tbl_queue_stats_0216`.`id` AS `id`,
       `tbl_queue_stats_0216`.`server_id` AS `server_id`,
       `tbl_queue_stats_0216`.`uniqueid` AS `uniqueid`,
       `tbl_queue_stats_0216`.`queue_datetime` AS `queue_datetime`,
       `tbl_queue_stats_0216`.`queue_timestamp` AS `queue_timestamp`,
       `tbl_queue_stats_0216`.`qname_id` AS `qname_id`,
       `tbl_queue_stats_0216`.`qagent_id` AS `qagent_id`,
       `tbl_queue_stats_0216`.`qevent_id` AS `qevent_id`,
       `tbl_queue_stats_0216`.`info1` AS `info1`,
       `tbl_queue_stats_0216`.`info2` AS `info2`,
       `tbl_queue_stats_0216`.`info3` AS `info3`,
       `tbl_queue_stats_0216`.`info4` AS `info4`,
       `tbl_queue_stats_0216`.`info5` AS `info5`
    from  `tbl_queue_stats_0216`
    union  all
    ...

| utf8                 | utf8_general_ci      |
```

So, Is there any way to partition a view?

Comment: What ENGINE are the tables?

Comment: Why did you "manually partition" the data into months?  Performance (which you probably did not get)?  Convenience (which you are complaining about)?  Other?

Comment: ENGINE is InnoDB for all tables. I did partition all tables into month because there are Millions of Records in single table. Creating single table for all data make the table exhaustive I guess. Is there any alternative for this?

Comment: A single table with 2 billion rows is probably less trouble than what you have -- except that `INT SIGNED` runs out of values at about 2 billion.

Answer (score 1):

Will you have a billion server_ids?  Perhaps you could use a smaller int, such as `MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED`, which is 3 bytes (instead of 4) and a limit of 16M.  Ditto for other ids.  (Smaller -> more cacheable -> less I/O -> faster)

Is `queue_timestamp` a timestamp?  If so, why `VARCHAR`?

`cast(info2 AS SIGNED)` -- You would be better off cleansing the data *before* inserting it, and then using an appropriate datatype (`INT`?).

*important:* Don't hide columns in functions (`DATE(a.queue_datetime)`), it inhibits using indexes; see below.

Are most of the fields really optional?  If not, say `NOT NULL`, instead of `NULL`.

*important:* Back to the question...  `UNION ALL` of 10 tables will perform similar to a `PARTITIONed` table where no "partition pruning" can occur.  But, the `UNION` is likely to be worse because it seems to generate the temp table containing all the data, then start filtering.  Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for the query.  (This should confirm or deny this supposition.  It could make a big difference.)

*important:* `INDEX(server_id, queue_datetime)` is likely to help performance.

So, the question now is whether "pruning" can occur.  The likely case is when query_datetime would limit the result to few partitions.  Are the tables based on `query_datetime`?  Are the `SELECTs` usually limited to one or two of the tables?

Given the correct answers to the above, and given the changes suggested, then changing from a `VIEW` to this will help significantly:

```
PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(query_datetime)) ...
```

But, as it turns out, partitioning is not really necessary.  The `INDEX` suggested above (together with the change to the `WHERE`) will do just as good on a *single* table.

But...  Some more questions.  You mentioned one `SELECT`; are there others?  Fixing the query/schema for one query may or may not help other queries.  Do you delete "old" tables/partitions?  If so partitioning can help nicely.

Answer those issues, then we can make a mid-course correction.

Answer (score 0):

Check the link given below .That may help you

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning.html

Comment: Table partitioning is explained very well, but Found nothing useful for my problem.

Comment: Yeah, partitioning is rarely a solution.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the query; then I may have something more constructive to say.

Comment: Please add `SHOW CREATE VIEW view_queue_stats`

Comment: (Note that link-only responses are not generally considered to be worthy of an answer here - maybe this could be a comment?).

Comment: @RickJames pls check edited question for output of SHOW CREATE VIEW view_queue_stats  – Dhruten Jul 7 at 9:39